# Fibonacci using Dynamic programming

Tags: java, recursion, dynamic-programming, fibonacci

I'm trying to code a slightly modified Fibonacci.

Here `n = (n-1)^2 + (n-2)`

Here's my code,

```
public static int fibonacci(int first, int second, int n){
    int[] memo = new int[n + 1];
    for(int i=0; i<= n; i++){
        memo[i] = -1;
    }
    return fibonacci(first, second, n, memo);

}

public static int fibonacci(int first, int second, int n, int[] memo){
    if(n == first || n == second) return n;

    if(memo[n] < 0) memo[n] =  (int)Math.pow(fibonacci(first, second, n-1, memo), 2) + fibonacci(first, second, n-2, memo);

    return memo[n];
}
```

I've tried debugging it several times over, but can't seem to figure out where the problem is. This code yields the next number, thus it yields F(6) for F(5). Any help appreciated. 
Please understand, I can solve this problem interactively, but that's not what I'm trying to do. I want to do it using this DP approach.

Comment: Can you edit your question to be more specific with what your problem is. Provide examples of what you expect to get and what you actually get.

Comment: put some comments in the code to make it more understandable

Answer (score 2):

You have a logic error in your code.

`first` and `second` is the value of the first and second terms in your sequence, and `n` is the index of value you want to find. But here, you compare index and value, which is wrong:

```
    if(n == first){
        return memo[n] = first;

    }
    if(n == second) return memo[n] = second;
```

It should be:

```
    if(n == 1){
        return memo[n] = first;

    }
    if(n == 2) return memo[n] = second;
```

Comment: Well that's because I'm calling the fibonacci function recursively with a decremented index.

Comment: @Zeus your code is only correct if `first` and `second` always equal to 0 and 1. And if that's the case, why do you need to pass them around? For example, if `first = -1` and `second = 3`, is your code correct?

Comment: Check the new code. Also it is assume that both first and second > 0

Comment: This code gives me one more as in F(6) is giving the value of F(7)

Comment: @Zeus `n` is 0-indexed (starting from 0) or 1-indexed (starting from 1)? In my solution, I assume that it is 0-indexed. You just need to change it accordingly otherwise.

Comment: n is 1 indexed, but the memo is 0 indexed.

Comment: Have you checked my amends, that's exactly what I am doing.

Comment: @Zeus it is exactly what you are doing only if `first` and `second` are always 1 and 2. And if that the case, why do you need to pass them around. Seem like you are not getting my point.